# Silverlight Bing map question

Tags: silverlight

I am planning to use Silverlight control for bing map. It will be used in a ASP.Net website.

Note: I am new to Silverlight and Bing map.

How the Silverlight bing map control will behave? Will the bing map service be called from the client browser or the web server?

Is there any architecture diagram related to this?

Please help.

Thanks

Lijo Cheeran Joseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about any architecture diagrams.  With the Silverlight control (the preferred control at this point, over the old AJAX control), the map service is called from the client browser...it is called from within the Silverlight application that hosts the map control, which like all Silverlight applications, runs exclusively on the client.

You could make calls to the Bing web services server-side, then use that data in some way, but if you're going after an interactive map, you will want the Silverlight control.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is on the following link:
http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/faq.aspx